# Implementing Razorpay Withdrawal System in Website

Tags: backend, payment-gateway, razorpay, banking

I'm working on a web application and need guidance on implementing a withdrawal system using Razorpay. The goal is to allow users to withdraw funds to their bank accounts. I've integrated Razorpay for payments but need assistance with the withdrawal process. Could someone provide insights or sample code on securely handling withdrawal requests and transferring money to users' bank accounts? Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In current situation majority of payment gateways have **paused onboarding** new merchants in India including **Razorpay**, so stop developing application developing over Razorpay **immediately**!. Its been a year. Check [here](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/rbi-rejects-57-payment-aggregator-applications/articleshow/97986302.cms?from=mdr).

According to your problem statement I would suggest [EaseBuzz](https://www.easebuzz.in/) or [Hatio](https://hatio.in/) but i'm  not sure about their quality. In Easebuzz they ask initial deposit.

Do some research.